# Clicking on java JTextArea or other methods

Tags: java, swing, file, pdf, jtextarea

I am currently working on Windows, and writing a simple Java application.

The application does a simple search for certain files, and I created a `JPanel` and a `JTextArea` and I add the text area to the panel, and I output the results, the file paths, on the text area using append.

So far so good.

Now, I wonder, if I wanted to be able to click on those paths (as if they were links) to open those files (they are either Word or PDF files), how do I do that?

I imagine this is probably going to require more than a couple of lines to code, but if anyone  could point me out in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)

Basically you want to use something like...

```
File file = new File(...);
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.edit(file);
```

or

```
desktop.open(file);
```

depending on if you want to edit or view the file (sometimes they are the same thing)

Take a look at the [JavaDocs for `java.awt.Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) for more details

**Updated with file opening example**

Based on feedback, I would recommend using a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) of `JTextArea` to list the matching the `File`s, this gives you more control over determining what the user has actually selected and designed to, well, list stuff

This example requires the user to perform a double click to open the file...

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FileListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FileListExample();
    }

    public FileListExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                File[] files = new File("...").listFiles();
                DefaultListModel<File> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
                for (File file : files) {
                    model.addElement(file);
                }
                JList<File> list = new JList<>(model);
                list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) && e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                            JList list = (JList) e.getComponent();
                            File file = (File) list.getSelectedValue();
                            try {
                                Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                                desktop.open(file);
                            } catch (IOException exp) {
                                exp.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

If you wanted to do something a little more fancy, you could even supply your own `ListCellRenderer`, for example...

[image: FileList]

```
public class FileListCellRenderer    extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        Icon icon = null;
        if (value instanceof File) {
            File file = (File) value;
            value = file.getName();
            FileSystemView view = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
            icon = view.getSystemIcon(file);
        }

        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus); 

        setIcon(icon);

        return this;

    }

}
```

Which can be applied using...

```
list.setCellRenderer(new FileListCellRenderer());
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I know how to open a file, my question is how do I make the text clickable? I want to somehow allow the user to click on a list of files and open that file. I can open the file, once I know which file the user has chosen, but I do not know how to create a jTextArea, or something else, where the user can actually choose a file.

Comment: @user79303 Really, you need to re-word you question. How is the file name displayed? Without context is very difficult to provide you with suggestions.  Try providing an actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will reduce the guess work and provide better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I suspected (but did not know for sure) that 'selecting the file' was part of the problem.  This question could have been better specified.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Given that people keep up-voting both answers would attest to that...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I thought the question was clear, sorry if it was not. The problem is simple: I am doing a query on a word, and I get back a list of files, ranked by how many times the word appear. I get the list back, no problem. Now I want to allow the user to select a file in that list, and treat it as if it were a link on a web page, so that clicking on it would open it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I like your suggestion, and I will look into it. I know that JTextArea was not good, it just worked for the first part, where i was displaying the files. For that it worked. I can look into your suggestion as a better implementation. Will that allow me to select the file and open it? Thank you.

Comment: @user79303 I would suggest that you output the file list into a JList and allow the user to either double click or through some other interaction open the file. I'll see if I can do an example soon

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help and quick reply, and sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: It worked liked a charm, and it was easier to implement than I thought it would be. Thank you again.

Comment: @user79303 Much easier then trying to make a `JTextArea` deal with it :P

Answer (score 3):

> I output the results, the file paths, on the `JTextArea`

See [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). A `JList` would be a much more natural component for this.  E.G. as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222943/418556).

[image]

See also [`FileBro`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) which uses a `JTree` for the file listing and the `Desktop` class as mentioned by @MadProgrammer.

[image]